# Wrong Fragment is loaded when resuming after my app was killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

In my App I have:

- DataManager class - a singleton which holds data
- Activity which shows a 'loading' fragment until the data is ready, and then once it is ready, it replaces it with a 'content' fragment. **(I do this with the replace() method, since I no longer have use for the 'loading' fragment)**

The following flow causes (sometimes) a null pointer exception:

- Open app and wait for the data to be loaded (meaning, until we get to the 'content' fragment)
- leave the app using the home button
- open the app after a while (after Android kills the app)

What happens is that the app resumes to the 'content' fragment, but the data from the DataManager is null.
This happens because Android kills my app, but when I resume, it saves the state, meaning it shows the 'content' fragment automatically.

Is there a way for me to tell the app not to create the 'content' fragment in this scenario? The solution I currently have in mind is to create a 'loading' Activity instead of a fragment, but i'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is either:

1. Persist your data to disk (e.g. SQLite DB), rather than retaining it as static data.
2. In your Activity `onCreate()`, check if you have data. If you do, continue on. If not, remove the content fragment and add back the loading fragment.

Comment: Regarding item 1 - I do persist it. But my Data manager needs to load it (async) and be ready BEFORE we get to the 'content' fragment.
Regarding item 2 - committing a fragment transaction ('remove' like you suggested) is not done immediately, and so the 'content' fragment's life-cycle methods are still called.

Comment: Alternatively then, I would have your content fragment and loading fragment be one and the same. Simply have the Fragment use a loader to do the data loading, and while loading, show the loading view. Once loading is complete, hide the loading view and show the content.

Comment: This does not fit the flow and architecture of my app. This DataManager supplies services to different parts of the app, and I need it ready before I get to the 'content' fragment

Comment: Then the only thing I can suggest (and trust me, I've actually had this same architectural issue) is to have a way to check if your data is available, and then just return from your lifecycle methods if the data is unavailable. Basically, just have a safety check anywhere that you try to access your data.

Comment: So isn't it better to just have a 'loading' Activity that opens a 'content' Activity instead of having all of these checks?

Comment: It's the same problem, just with a different architecture. Android will still save your Activity stack -- even after the app is removed from memory.

Comment: Meaning: Activity A starts Activity B -> app is killed by Android -> resuming app shows Activity B? Right... that makes sense :/ So it seems there is no escaping checking that the data is available... unless there is some Fragment life cycle magic I'm not aware of

Comment: Yup, as far as I know, there's not really a way around that. You can add `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` to your Activity, but that only affects launches from the launcher icon -- you'd still have the issue if you resume from Recent Apps. I'd highly suggest seeing if there's a way you could asynchronously request data from your DataManager, and have it internally cache it when loaded, but just have all consumers of the data *expect* that it may not be instantaneous -- even though it will be after the initial load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that in the content fragment before loading other views and all, check if your data is ready. if not then start the loading fragment and resume content fragment when it's ready.

e.g in OnCreate

```
    if(!dataLoaded){ 
        replaceFragment(LoadingFragment)
       }
```